# Would it be okay to ask for help finding specific books I've previously read, but forgot the author and title?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

There are a couple of books (one about wolves; one about bears) that I read decades ago that I'd like to reread.  I don't know the authors, I don't know the titles, but I could describe them in enough detail so that anyone who had read them would recognize them.

Obviously, I will do some serious Googling first, but if that fails, would a question here be on topic or not?

(These are not biology books; they are definitely TGO-type books.)

This is not a duplicate of [Is asking for recommendations of books ok?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-asking-for-recommendations-of-books-ok) because, to quote @Chenmunka

> [that question] asks about recommending any book on a subject, this
>   question is about finding a specific lost book.

Comment: Test question has been posted on the main site [Book about wolves raised by a man, his wife and a German Shepherd: familiar to anyone?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/book-about-wolves-raised-by-a-man-his-wife-and-a-german-shepherd-familiar-to-a)

Answer (score 4):

Questions like this are regularly posted to the Scifi SE,

- [Man serves a sentence for the murder he will be allowed to commit in the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74024/man-serves-a-sentence-for-the-murder-he-will-be-allowed-to-commit-in-the-future)
- [A Book where an Animal is advertising itself to be eaten](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146318/a-book-where-an-animal-is-advertising-itself-to-be-eaten)
- [A man wakes up from stasis alone on a spaceship then creates the greatest story in history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/a-man-wakes-up-from-stasis-alone-on-a-spaceship-then-creates-the-greatest-story)

Which to me says that this type and format of question is considered a good fit for a stackexchange site.

As long as we limit the books identified to being about the outdoors I don't see a problem with these types of questions.

Comment: I agree in general that these questions might be a good fit but I disagree that Identify this questions are generally well regarded. Jeff Attwood wrote a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) warning people away from these types of questions. Like you pointed out in SciFi.SE these questions have been well received. On Movies.SE they are a point of controversy. In SO and Programmers.SE they are banned. Like I said I'm open to the questions, and personally find value in the questions so I'd be supportive of them here.